# How to disable hints for certain keywords in python elpy

Tags: python, elpy

I enabled elpy mode for python and I get hints when I type a keyword. Also I have yasnippets. Unfortunately, when I type "for" keyword, elpy gives me a useless hint, blocking `<tab>` key for yasnippet expansion. I have to click left - right to get rid of it.

[image]

How can I disable hints for "for" keyword?

Answer (score 0):

If you type for[tab] very fast, it should work and expand your yasnippet. You can set `company-idle-delay` to a longer time, like 1 (sec) to have more time for this; the default is quite short at 0.1 sec. If you want the tip and it is not showing, I think you can get it with `M-x company-complete`.

If the tip shows, I think you can type C-g to get rid of the hint, then press tab to activate the yasnippet. Alternatively, type `M-x yas-expand`.

I am not sure you can get it to ignore for otherwise, or if you really want to. What would you do if you wanted completion on something that started with for, e.g. a variable name, other function, etc.?